# Error Can't use object of type std Class as array in my code

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

this is my function in model

```
public function get_user($username, $password) {

    $p = md5($password);

    $this->db->select('userid, userfullname, useraddress');
             ->from('user');
             ->where('username', $username);
             ->where('userpassword', $p);
    $q = $this->db->get();
    if ($q->num_rows() == 1){
        return $q->row(); 
    }
    else ($q->num_rows() > 1){
        return $q->result_array();
    }
}
```

and this is my code in controller, I want to return the value of $q to result[]
        $this->load->model('User_model');

```
    $username = $this->post('username');
    $password = $this->post('password');
    $token    = $this->post('token');

    $result   = [];

    if($this->security->xss_clean($username, TRUE) && $this->security->xss_clean($password, TRUE)) {

        $result = $this->User_model->get_user($username, $password);

    }
```

I've got error Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: You should probably consider you have a schema error (missing unique constraint on username) if you can get more than one row returned. You should probably also return something sensible (or throw an exception) if no rows are returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do in your controller this?

```
$result   = []; // $result is set as empty array

if($this->security->xss_clean($username, TRUE) && $this->security->xss_clean($password, TRUE)) {

  // notice the [] 
  $result[] = $this->User_model->get_user($username, $password);

}
```

Or maybe better would be:

```
$this->db->select('userid, userfullname, useraddress')
             ->where('username', $username)
             ->where('userpassword', $p)
$q = $this->db->get('user');

if ($q->num_rows() == 1) {
    return array($q->row());
}
else($q->num_rows() > 1) {
    return $q->result_array();
}


//  in controller
$result   = [];

if($this->security->xss_clean($username, TRUE) && $this->security->xss_clean($password, TRUE)) {
     $result = $this->User_model->get_user($username, $password);
}
```

Comment: Is it different than other answer ?

Comment: I'm sorry if that my code was false. My question is not about that. I want to insert the return value of my query to $result[] but I've got error Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you don't need `;` in each line, to make chain method

```
$this->db->select('userid, userfullname, useraddress')
             ->from('user')
             ->where('username', $username)
             ->where('userpassword', $p);
    $q = $this->db->get();
```

Or better combine all

```
$q  = $this->db->select('userid, userfullname, useraddress')
        ->from('user')
        ->where('username', $username)
        ->where('userpassword', $p)
        ->get();
```

Comment: I'm sorry if that my code was false. My question is not about that. I want to insert the return value of my query to $result[] but I've got error Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: @M.Syafi'iAsy'ari : did you try what I ans ? and please share what error in which line you are getting ?

Comment: @user2468 yes, I've been tried your answer. Error in return $q->row()

Comment: @M.Syafi'iAsy'ari : try `return $row = $q->row_array();` instead `return $q->row();`

Comment: @M.Syafi'iAsy'ari : Also share what error you are getting ?

Comment: Severity: Notice Message : Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: @M.Syafi'iAsy'ari :  did you tried `return $row = $q->row_array();` instead `return $q->row();` ?

Comment: @M.Syafi'iAsy'ari : may be you are using wrong password try to comment both where condition line and try ?

Comment: @M.Syafi'iAsy'ari : actuall you didn't check for no result , if you got not result what will happen ?

Comment: You would receive an empty stdclass object. Your error is probably due to the fact that your are getting and object and assigning it to an array.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, in a function where both inputs are unique why would you ever expect more than 1 user to show up? Secondly, I have to assume this function is somehow related to login, thus it should return and error if no results are returned. Thirdly, you are returning two different types from the model, a `row()` which as an object and an `result_array` which is obviously an array.

Then you are applying, usually, the returned `row()` to an array `$result[]`. Weird. Let's fix that...

public function get_user($username, $password)
{

```
$p = md5($password);
$this->db->select('userid, userfullname, useraddress')
    ->from('user')
    ->where('username', $username)
    ->where('userpassword', $p);
$q = $this->db->get();
if ($q->num_rows() == 1) {
    return $q->row_array();
} else {
    return false;
}
```

}

Now you will always return an array not an object with `row_array()`, or an empty array on failure (more or less than 1 user found with those details). Let's be honest, whats the likelihood users have the same name and password, close to 0!

So now when you assign it like this:

```
    $result   = [];

    if($this->security->xss_clean($username, TRUE) && $this->security->xss_clean($password, TRUE)) {

        $result = $this->User_model->get_user($username, $password);

    }
```

You have to understand that to get a value of `$result` you have to do this:

`$result['userid']` which may result in a notice if the model returned false so you have to check for that and propagate the appropriate error before getting values!